# How to Convert twitter api timestamp to unix time in vba excel

Tags: sqlite, vba, excel

I am trying to convert a twitter timestamp string to Unix time (seconds since epoch). I have been searching for a while but cant find anything that works. Anyone know how to convert "Mon Sep 24 03:35:21 +0000 2012" to unix time? Or if not, with a sqlite db time function?

Comment: You will have to reformat that string in order for VBA to be able to recognize is as a date.  To convert that date to Unix time you can use `DateDiff("s", date1, date2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your *Mon Sep 24 03:35:21 +0000 2012* as a string, this returns a Unix (aka POSIX) date as a long.

```
Dim tt As String, ut As Long
tt = "Mon Sep 24 03:35:21 +0000 2012"
ut = ((CDate(Mid(tt, 5, 6) & ",  " & Right(tt, 4) & Mid(tt, 11, 9)) + (IIf(Mid(tt, 21, 1) = Chr(45), -1, 1) * TimeSerial(Mid(tt, 22, 2), Mid(tt, 24, 2), 0))) - 25569) * 86400
Debug.Print ut
```

The result will be 1348457721 for the sample you've provided.

**EDIT:**

Modified above code to account for both positive and negative UTC timezone offsets.

Comment: What about the timezone? Actually reference to some really working date time parser tested against a standard specification would be better then ad hoc code with 7 magic constants inside

Comment: @xmojmr - I've modified the above to compensate for UTC offsets but I couldn't figure out any way to reduce or remove the *magical* constants generated by the number of seconds in a day (e.g. *86,400*) or the number of days from Dec 31, 1899 to Jan 1, 1970 (e.g. *25,569*). The other 5 *magical* constants remain invisible to my eyes unless you were referring to the character placement for the different elements in a fixed length string.